# How to copy contents of one file into a after a specific line in another file

Tags: python, regex

How to copy contents of one file into a after a specific line in another file?

I would like to copy the contents of file1 after the following string:

```
<!-- INSERT SMART FIELDS HERE -->
```

My code so far.

```
file1 = open('newfile.xml')
file2 = open('../file.xml', "rb+")
regex = re.compile(r"<[^*]-- INSERT SMART FIELDS HERE -->")
 for line in file1.readlines():
   for comment in file2.readlines():
       our_match = regex.findall(comment)
             if match in our_match:
```

Comment: Does this work? If no, what does *not* work?

Comment: Not that it doesn't work. I just don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to read the first file until you find the line you are looking for and aftewards just read each line of the first file and write to the second file.

```
regex = re.compile(r"<[^*]-- INSERT SMART FIELDS HERE -->")
line_found = False

with open('newfile.xml') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        if re.match(line):
            line_found = True
            break
    with open('../file.xml', "w+") as file2:
        if line_found:
            for line in file1:
                file2.write(line)
```

Comment: this appears to wipe out 2nd file completely

Comment: actually I dont need to read anything in file1. Just want to copy the entire contents of file1 into file2. But only copy it after a certain line in file2.

Comment: to copy them you have to read them, you can modify the script above to fit your use case easily